# Difference between so called and called so

Tags: adverb-placement

What is the difference between **so called** and **called so** in the following sentences?

> The active voice is **so called** because the person denoted by the
>   subject acts.
>  The active voice is **called so** because the
>   person denoted by the subject acts.

**so** as an adverb is used to refer back to something that has already been mentioned, so according to me the second sentence sounds more correct.

Answer (score 1):

"so-called" (usually hyphenated) is used in attributive position, that is, before the noun it refers to, for example:

- The **so-called "active voice"** is a form of the verb in which the subject is the one that does the action.

Instead, in "called so" (which is used in predicative position, that is, after the noun it refers to) *so* is an adverb equivalent to "thus" or "(in) this/that way":

- The **active voice** is **called so** (= thus, in this way) because the subject performs the action, while in the passive voice the subject receives the action.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that *so-called* is orders of magnitude more common than *called so*.  Everyone uses *so-called*, but you could probably go your whole life as an English speaker without saying *called so*.

Comment: @snailboat Indeed!

Answer (score 0):

**So called** is a specific idiom meaning that a large number of people use the term or phrase, without regard to whether their usage is correct.  It is often, but not always used to point out that people are wrong to call an object or person the thing they are called.  "The *so called* sports hero was convicted of several crimes today."  The idiom can also be used when the term is correct, but many people would not know why the term is correct, such as in your example.

The phrase **called so** is not a specific idiom, but it is grammatically correct.  You can use it if you would like, but it will not carry the extra weight or meaning of being an idiom.